# Curse of the SKlearn Classifiers

Tags: python, scikit-learn, artificial-intelligence, classification, prediction

Suppose we have 1,000 beads 900 red and 100 blue ones. When I run the problem through SKlearn classifier ensembles,

**score = clf.score(X_test, y_test)**

They come up with scores of around .9 however, when I look at the predictions I see that it has predicted all of them to be Red and this is how it comes up with %90 accuracy! Please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Better yet, what does it mean when this happens? Is there a better way to measure accuracy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might happen when you have an imbalanced dataset, and you chose `accuracy` as your metric. The reason is that by `always` deciding red, the model is actually doing OK in terms of accuracy, but as you noticed, the model is useless!
In order to overcome this issue, you have some alternatives such as:
 1. Use another metric, like AUC (area under roc curve), etc.
 2. Use different weights for classes, and put more weight on the minority class.
 3. Use simple over-sampling or under-sampling methods, or other more sophisticated ones like SMOTE, ADASYN, etc.

You can also take a look at [this article](https://medium.com/analytics-ai-swedbank/imbalanced-learning-in-banking-1bd3868a496d).
This problem you face is quite common in real world applications.

Comment: Thank you your explanation was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

You have an imbalanced classification problem. You are write, by default score measures accuracy, but it is recommended to look at recall and precision for imbalanced data.

[This video explains it better than I could](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aDW44NPhNw0&t=3s)

The video above demonstrates you what you should do in order to measure classification performance in your data. To deal with data imbalance, you check imblearn library:

https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html

Comment: Thank you for your explanation